# How to use RS485 on beaglebone black

Tags: android, c++, linux, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a beaglebone black with kernel 4.4-ti, I wonder how to use the RS485 on UART4 (P9.11 and P9.13). There is a overlay of 'BB-UART4-RS485' and when I try to load it, it said 'file exists'.

There is the pin P9.27 which is about the DE/RE, should I use it?

I want to connect to a device which has modbus A, mobus B and ground. It is using half duplex.

I try to simply connect the tx and rx on BBB to A and B on the device, there is communication. But the received message is some garbage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I can only help with the hardware aspect: You need an RS485 driver chip, or a cape with such a chip. Several manufacturers make suitable chips. One example is the SN65HVD72.

For half duplex operation, it is important to connect both pins RE and DE to P9.27, because the driver chip needs to know whether to receive or drive.

The pins named A and B connect to the Modbus, and pins R and D connect to UART4.

The chip also needs 3.3V for its power supply, which is available on the cape connector.